# Bash script to display files path and sizes in the directories based on extension

Tags: bash, shell

Currently i need to create a bash script to let user enter a directory path e.g /home and it will loop through the entire home directory and display a summary of  the file path and size of the file based on file extension (.exe, .mp3, .avi).

So for example, in my home directory, there are files that have the following file format
- .exe
- .pdf
- .txt
- .mp3
- .avi
- .mp4

So when i run the script, it should display a summary on the console and then it remove the files.

```
Filename    Filesize   Filepath
---------   ---------  ---------
test1.exe   5kb        /home/program/
test2.exe   6kb        /home/program/
test3.mp3   10mb       /home/music/
test4.avi   15mb       /home/video/

4 files are removed
```

Below are the code that i have tried to attempt.

```
function check {
    for file in $1/*      
    do
    if [ -d "$file" ]
    then
            check $file                          
    else
           ##check for the file
           if [ $(head -c 4 "$file") = "%EXE" || $(head -c 4 "$file") = "%MP3" || $(head -c 4 "$file") = "%AVI" ]; then
         find $filepath -iregex ".*\.\(exe\|mp3\|avi\)" > log
                     rm -r $file
                     my $filecounter +=1;
         print "$filecounter files are removed"
           fi
    fi
    done     
}
print "Please enter file path:";
chomp( my $filepath = <STDIN> );
check $filepath
```

Comment: You didn't ask any question. What is it that you want to know? BTW, in your posting, you are talking about file extensions, but in your code, you investigate the first 4 characters of each file. Plus, your say that you want to list the files, but in your code, you attempt to delete them. You need to be more precise in your writing if you expect helpful answers....

Comment: BTW, the `-r` option of `rm` doesn't make sense when used with a file. See the *rm*  man page.

Comment: Hi user1934428, sorry that i did not phrase my question properly. That code is i tried to find online. What i want to do is to list out all the files that fit into the criteria where file ext is .exe, .mp3, .avi

After displaying the list of files that fit into that requirement, it will delete the files

Comment: So, why then are you looking **into** the files, if you are only interested in the extensions?

Comment: you meant "find $filepath -iregex ".*\.\(exe\|mp3\|avi\)" > log"?

Comment: No. The `find` command is unrelated, as I don't see what it is doing here (you are running a *find* for **every** file which you are deleting - this doesn't make sense). Your *head* command is looking into the files ... I mean, you wrote the script, you know what it is doing, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

To list the files in directory $mydir and remove them, use

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in $mydir/*.{exe,mp3,avi}
do 
    rm -v $f
done
```

Using *nullglob* ensures that the loop won't be executed if there is no file matching a certain extension. The `-v` option of *rm* ensures that the files are reported to stdout.

Comment: For the mentioned solution, it will not display the list of files that fit into the criteria and show their path right, it will just remove them?

Comment: @Mat : It does show AND remove them - all the files ending in exe, mp3 or avi. Please read what I explained: *... ensures that the files are reported to stdout*.